# What is minimal sample Gradle project for ANTLR4 (with antlr plugin)?

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I have created new Gradle project, added

```
apply plugin: 'antlr'
```

and

```
dependencies {
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3"
```

to `build.gradle`.

Created `src/main/antlr/test.g4` file with the following content

```
grammar test;
r   : 'hello' ID;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

But it doesn't work. No java source files generated (and no error occurred).

What I missed?

Project is here: https://github.com/dims12/AntlrGradlePluginTest2

**UPDATE**

I found my sample is actually works, but it put code into `\build\generated-src` which I was not expecting :shame:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will add onto other answers here.

**Issue 1**: Generated source files are placed in `build/generated-src` folder.

I found [this discussion](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-to-configure-where-antlr-generates-source-files-td3320837.html), but the solution there (setting `outputDirectory` property) is a **bad** idea. If you do `gradle clean build` command, this will clear out your *entire* source directory. The discussion there gives a good explanation as to why you should not

> the antlr generated sources are generated into a 
>   subdirectory of the "build" folder like all other artifacts, which are 
>   generated during the build. Furthermore your generated directory 
>   projectRoot/build/generated-src/antlr/main is added to the java 
>   sourceset definition to be sure its considered compileJava task. 
>   If you write the antlr generated source directly to the src/main/java 
>   folder you're polluting your source folder with output of your build 
>   process. ...  Polluting your source folder during your build is an 
>   antipattern I think.

However, if you want to do this, you can add a gradle task to copy the generated files to the build directory.

```
generateGrammarSource << {
    println "Copying generated grammar lexer/parser files to main directory."
    copy {
        from "${buildDir}/generated-src/antlr/main"
        into "src/main/java"
    }
}
```

---

**Issue 2**: Generated source files do not have package attribute set.

To solve this issue, add something like the following near the top of the grammar file:

```
@header {
package com.example.my.package;
}
```

Comment: the header must be after `grammar Name;` and copying the generated source does not make sense. Whats wrong with `build`? if you really wanna move the gen-src then use `generateGrammarSource { outputDirectory = file("src/gen/java/")}` see answer by mawalker.

Comment: @Kip This way it gives me an error that "duplicate class found in "build/generated-src/...". What should I do about it?

Comment: Do not copy generated classes into your source directory! Gradle is able to include the generated-src directory while compiling the project. This ways the classes are always generated but also available for compiling. Mixing generated and static sources leads to duplications on the classpath like you expected.

Answer (score 12):

What helped me is two things:

- Add header:`@header{ package com.example.something.antlrparser; }` to the grammar file directly after the `grammar test;` declaration.
- Place the grammar file in corresponding folder, i.e. `src/main/antlr/com/example/something/antlrparser/grammar.g4`

Now when I run the `generateGrammarSource` gradle task, `.java` files are generated in `/build/generated-src/antlr/main/com/example/something/antlrparser/*.java` and they are automatically picked up by IntelliJ as well as compilable by gradle.

The `build.gradle` file is just:

```
group 'com.example.something'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'antlr'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5" // use ANTLR version 4
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
generateGrammarSource {
    outputDirectory = file("src/main/java/com/example/parser")
}
```

add this to your grammar after your "grammar ";

```
@header {
    package com.example.parser;
}
```

Tested and working with [Java8 grammar from antlr example grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4)

Additional Link(s):

[Here is a short guide of the Antlr plugin from docs.gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html)

Answer (score 5):

For Issue 2:

you can configure in the gradle.build:

```
  generateGrammarSource {
        maxHeapSize = "64m"
        arguments += ["-visitor", 
                      "-long-messages", 
                      "-package", "your.package.name"]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A snippet is included in the Gradle "all" distribution under the "snippets" folder. You can also simply browse the snippet on GitHub.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/snippets/antlr

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle sample noted by @Mark Vieira only got me halfway there.  I found that I had to specify the package in the header of my ANTLR grammar file in order for everything to be seen in both directions (generated code able to access hand-written code and vice-versa).

```
grammar MyGrammar;

@header {
    package com.mypackage;
}
```

Prior to switching to Gradle, I had been using the ANTLR plugin in IntelliJ, which filled in the package for me.  Upon switching to Gradle, the package went away, which caused problems.

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655920/1877143

Comment: If you put your grammar files in packages, it will do it automatically. Like if you have `src/main/antlr/com/mypackage/MyGrammar.g`, then it will put the generated files in `com.mypackage`.

Comment: I take that back... that puts the output files in the right place but still doesn't add the package line to the generated source

Answer (score 0):

Gradle STS plugin doesn't generate source files for antlr4.  It generates the misleading output as:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      generateGrammarSource
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:generateGrammarSource UP-TO-DATE
```

Uninstalled this old plugin and used from command line..It works !

[image: Gradle STS plugin doesn't generate source files for antlr4. Need to Use new plugin or command line]